# how to scrape web pages whose url links does not show page numbers

Tags: python

```
    headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.50'}

    website = 'https://www.binance.com/en/markets'


    response= requests.get('https://www.binance.com/en/markets', headers=headers)

    for page in range(0, 5):
       soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    results = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'css-leyy1t'})
```

My objective is to scrape 'https://www.binance.com/en/markets' but all the pages url shows the same thing,no page number to edit in python so that i can loop through in order to scrape all the pages.

I expect to see a url like this 'https://www.cars.com/shopping/results/?page=6&page_size=20&list_price_max=&makes[]=mercedes_benz&maximum_distance=20&models[]=&stock_type=cpo&zip='

Comment: Check https://www.binance.com/bapi/composite/v1/public/marketing/symbol/list and https://www.binance.com/bapi/asset/v2/public/asset/asset/get-all-asset

Comment: if you want to use webscraping to collect this data you will probably need to use Selenium as the page data is loaded via JavaScript.   You may want to check over their APIs and see if any of those can get you the data you want at the interval you want at no charge.  https://www.binance.com/en/binance-api